# CakePHP code generation is not working for a table without primary key [Newbie]

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

**Conditions of the problem**

I have a simple cakephp project that works fine. And I want to add two more pages which will show data from the following tables:

First table contains primary key
[image: first]

The second table contains foreign key

[image: last]

In order to create those 2 pages I use code generation: `./cake bake all table_name`

**Problem**

When I run this command for the first table, it works fine, but when I run the script for the second table, it doesn't generate *views* (I mean *.ctp files). The error is the following:

> Error: Cannot generate views for models with no primary key

I tried to create index.ctp inside src/template/second_table/index.ctp, but cakephp returns this error:

> Unable to locate an object compatible with paginate

How do I correct that? Can I create views manually?

Comment: Doesn't bake prompt you for table relationships?  Also, the convention would be if your first table is named `names` and second is named `details` the foreign key in details would be `name_id`. Then it should work automagically.

Comment: I changed the column name in the second table as you said, but the error is the same, it doesn't point on any relations between tables: Error: Cannot generate views for models with no primary key

Comment: You followed the conventions? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

Comment: I think yes, but maybe I miss something. I tried to do the following: 1. Create table `create table names (id int not null auto_increment primary key, email varchar(255));` 2. create details table `create table details (name_id int not null, adress varchar (255));` 3. Add foreign key: `alter table details add constraint fk_details foreign key (name_id) references names (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;` 4. `./cake bake all names` 5. `./cake bake all details` -> same error

Comment: I haven't used `bake` in a while but I thought it would ask if there are related tables and you would pick `details`.  Maybe somebody else will come along.

Comment: For both errors the issue is exactly what they say. It has no primary key, so it can't output the default bake templates because it works off of the primary key. Same thing for the paginate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are still having problem with making table correctly.And looks like your second table don't have primary key:

*Simply follow cakephp conventions as following:*

**names table**

```
create table names (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  first_name varchar(255),
  last_name varchar(255)
)
```

**details table:**

```
create table details (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  name_id int, 
  email varchar(255),
  address varchar(255)
)
```

Now go to the your project directory path and within bin (E:\xampp\htdocs\blogs\bin> for mine):

```
1.cake bake all names
2.cake bake all details
```

Completely follow ([cakephp conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html)) which will make things easier.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, the problem was about conventions. I did all as you said and everything works fine. Thank you so much! But I need to clarify one more thing: when table with foreign key contains multiple words (details_info, for example), how can I access this page? If I try to use url like localhost/cakephp/detailsinfo, it returns **Unable to locate an object compatible with paginate**

Comment: You are welcome ! If you are retrieving pagination data you need to provide page in url..like localhost/cakephp/detailsinfo/1..If you look after some function like view(which is made from cake bake) you can understand that quite well.